# Running a setInterval() timer in a loop - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a `setInterval()` timer that is used to run a progress bar. Now, when the timer is over or when a particular button is pressed, I want to cancel the timer, make some changes on the page and then restart the entire timer function again. A normal `for()` loop will not work in this case, obviously, since I want to wait till the timer completes itself or a button is pressed.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
score = 0;
question_counter = 1;
var counter = 25;
var num_q = 5;

for(var x=0; x < num_q; x++){
    //Loop the timer function here
}

function timer_loop(){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        $("#timer").attr("style","width: "+ ((counter/25)*100) +"%;");
        $("#timeleft").html("TIME LEFT &nbsp; <b>" + counter + "s</b>")
        if(counter < 20 && counter > 15){
            $("#timer").attr("class","progress-bar progress-bar-success");
        }else if(counter < 15 && counter > 6){
            $("#timer").attr("class","progress-bar progress-bar-warning");
        }else if(counter < 6){
            $("#timer").attr("class","progress-bar progress-bar-danger");
            beep();
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            $("#q_header").html("Question " + question_counter);
            question_counter++;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);

    $(".btn").click(function(event){
        $(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
        console.log($(this).id);
        score = score + counter;
        $("#scoreshow").html("CURRENT SCORE &nbsp;<b>" + score + "</b>")
        clearInterval(interval);
        counter = 25;
        $(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this "timer loop"?

---

**EDIT**
This is basically for a "quiz" app where a timer runs for "x" seconds during which if the user answers, the time remaining is added to his/her score and the next question is displayed with a "resetted" timer. If the timer runs out anyway, then the next question is displayed with no addition to the score and a "resetted" timer.

Comment: `setInterval` already runs a function in a loop, why do you need to call it in a loop? Start it when the page loads, clear it when the user presses the button, and then start it again after the user makes their changes.

Comment: @Barmar I just added an edit. Please check for clarification.

Comment: @Barmar, I think I got what you are saying. Will try it out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar for the simple answer.
Just had to remove the `clearInterval()` from both places and it works perfectly. As rightly said, `setInterval()` is anyway a loop, as compared to `setTimeout()`.